# How to get root category on product.tpl - Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I would like to get root category on product.tpl with Prestashop.
It means if I have a product which is in `cat1>cat2>cat3`, I should get "cat1". 
Is it possible ?

I tried `$product->id_category_default`, but I only get the current category.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new smarty variable in ProductController and use getParentsCategories() function for your product category.